# App service fabric not starting

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I keep getting errors related to conflicting ports. When I set a breakpoint inside Program.cs at the line containing

```
ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync
```

It actually stops there more then once per service in the service fabric project which is obviously why it's trying to bind to the same port more than once! Why is it doing this all of a sudden?!

```
HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'https://+:446/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.
```

Comment: Did you specify the port number for endpoint in ServiceManifest? How many endpoint do you have per one service? Could you please show us the code where you create listeners?

Answer (score 1):

In your application manifest, you define how many instances of your service you want, the common mistake people do is to set this number to more than 1, and it will fail, because your local cluster show 5 nodes, but they all run on same machine, and the machine port will be used only in the first instance started.

Set the number of instances to 1 and you won't see multiple entrance on main  entry-point at program.cs.

Make it configurable from ApplicationParameters, so you can define these number per environment.

Comment: This does work but the really weird thing is it used to work with 5 and in fact on my co-workers machine it still does!

Comment: Check if his machines are using the same configuration version, check in service fabric how many instances of that service are running. Check also if any other service is using the same port with this command "netstat.exe –a –n –o".
Also, take a note that instanceCount -1 is different of 1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the httplistener is trying to bind to a port that is already in use. The cause of this problem can be one of the following.

- Another process is already using the port. Try `netstat -ano` to find out the process that is using the port and then `tasklist /fi "pid eq <pid of process>"` to find the process name.
- Maybe you are starting your development cluster as a multi node instance. That way several nodes on one machine are trying to access the same port.
- Maybe you have a frontend and an api that you want to run on the same port then you have to use the path-based binding capabilities of http.sys (If you are using the WebListener)

If this fails could you please post a snippet of the `ServiceManifest.xml`.
There should be a line defining your endpoint `<Endpoint Protocol="https" Type="Input" Port="446" />`

Comment: Setting it to a 1 node cluster locally makes it work but I never had to do that before? i've been working with this SF project for a couple of months now!

Answer (score 0):

You say that you didn't have to set the instance count before and that could be because you have the option to use Publish profiles that can differ from Cloud vs Local deployment. The profile will point to the corresponding Application Parameters file in which you can set the instance count to 1 for local deployments.

Perhaps something happened to your publish profiles?

[image]

ApplicationParameters/Local.1Node.xml:

[image: ApplicationParameters/Local.1Node.xml]